# Observable/List or Property: exception thrown in listener not "seen" by unit test

Tags: java, javafx, junit, properties, observablelist

The scenario: a class with some observable field (be it a simple property or observableList, doesn't matter) with a listener to this field. The listener throws an exception if client code tries to change the observable's value to anything invalid.

When testing this behavior, the exception is thrown as expected (shown on the console) but the test method doesn't see it. That is a test expecting the exception will fail.

Feels like I'm missing something obvious:

- why does this happen?
- anything wrong with my setup/expectation?
- how to fix: either make the tests pass, or change the setup or anything else?

The example:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

/**
 * Trying to dig into issue with expected exceptions. They are shown
 * on the console, but not seen by test runner.
 * 
 * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
 */
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)

public class ExceptionFailingTest {

    @Test (expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testExceptionFromListChangeListener() {
        ListOwner owner = new ListOwner();
        owner.getObjects().clear();
    }

    /**
     * Exception thrown in a ChangeListener is not seen by test.
     */
    @Test (expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testExceptionFromPropertyListener() {
        ListOwner owner = new ListOwner();
        owner.getProperty().setValue(null);
    }

    public static class ListOwner {

        private ObservableList objects;
        private Property property;

        public ListOwner() {
            objects = FXCollections.observableArrayList("some", "things", "in", "me");
            objects.addListener((ListChangeListener)c -> objectsChanged(c));
            property = new SimpleObjectProperty(this, "property", "initial");
            property.addListener((src, ov, nv) -> propertyChanged(ov));
        }

        public Property getProperty() {
            return property;
        }

        protected void propertyChanged(Object ov) {
            if (property.getValue() == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("property must not be empty");
        }

        public ObservableList getObjects() {
            return objects;
        }

        protected void objectsChanged(Change c) {
            if (c.getList().isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalStateException("objects must not be empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code that invokes the listener ([lines 175-188](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/binding/ExpressionHelper.java)) catches exceptions thrown by the listener and passes them directly to the FX Application Thread's uncaught exception handler, preventing them from propagating to your test case. This is documented in.... oh, just kidding. It doesn't seem to be documented at all. I think the only way to veto changes is to subclass the property implementation and override `set` and `setValue`. Lists are harder, but possible.

Comment: @James_D darn again ... thanks! Yeah, usually do for properties (in its invalidated) so never noticed before having that damned list that must not be empty. hmm... so back to quare one thinking

Comment: tried to wrap the list into a subclassed SimpleListProperty and check in invalidated: dead end, because the invalidated is called from ... a ListChangeListener to the wrapped list ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, exceptions thrown by listeners are essentially suppressed. This actually seems like a reasonable API design choice (though some documentation would be nice): by the time a change listener (or list change listener) is invoked, the value of the property or list has been changed. So if you had multiple listeners, one listener throwing an exception would effectively veto other listeners observing the change, but would not veto the change itself. It's also hard to see how a (JPA-style) "rollback" could be implemented: if a second listener threw an exception, the first listener would have to be "unnotified" somehow.

So I think the way to veto changes is not with listeners at all, but by subclassing the appropriate property/list class and overriding the appropriate methods that modify the observable.

For example, to have an observable list that is never empty, you could do something like the following [CAVEAT: not intended to be production quality, just an illustration of the approach]:

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase;

public class NonEmptyObservableList<E> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<E> {

    private final List<E> source ;

    public NonEmptyObservableList(List<E> source) {
        if (source.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("List cannot be empty");
        }
        this.source = source ;
    }


    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return source.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return source.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, E element) {
        source.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doSet(int index, E element) {
        return source.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doRemove(int index) {
        if (size() <= 1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("List cannot be empty");
        }
        return source.remove(index);
    }

}
```

Note that calling `clear()` on this list will, somewhat arbitrarily, leave the "last" element in place. Here's a unit test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class NonEmptyObservableListTest {

    @Test (expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testExceptionFromListChangeListener() {
        NonEmptyObservableList<String> list = new NonEmptyObservableList<>(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two")));
        list.clear();
    }


    @Test
    public void testSizeOnClear() {
        NonEmptyObservableList<String> list = new NonEmptyObservableList<>(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two")));
        try {
            list.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // squash exception to test list size...
        }
        Assert.assertSame("List size is not 1", list.size(), 1);
    }
}
```

You could consider also overriding `clear()` to "atomically veto" the change:

```
@Override
public void clear() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("List cannot be empty");
}
```

which would leave the list unchanged on calling `clear()` (instead of leaving one element in it), though it is hard to cover all possibilities (`list.subList(0, list.size()).clear()`...).

It would be interesting to try to create a general vetoable observable list (with a `Predicate<List<E>>` to determine if a change were allowed), but doing so in an efficient manner would be quite challenging (and is left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: thanks, that puts me on track to a possible solution :-) Actually, we already have a vetoable list in the bowels of fx (callled VetoableListDecorator), not sure what its status - list implementations before the Big Overhaul around fx 2 were severely lacking .. On the other hand, asking the question had the usual effect of making me re-think my real requirement <g> Which seems to be "if empty otherwise, have one particular stand-in element" in the list. Which I could do by wrapping into a ListProperty and add/remove the stand-in in its invalidated.

Comment: @kleopatra There might be a simple way to implement that last option using a [`TransformationList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/TransformationList.html).

Comment: had been thinking about it, but it's unmodifiable so I can't expose it for modification by the user. BTW, had to back out of the ListProperty trick (the requirement is like in my last comment plus "remove the stand-in again if not empty otherwise" ... dooh ... my brain sleeping or what ;-) We MUST NOT alter the list in a listener (trick does so) - getting away with the addition but not with the removal. Looks like a custom impl as you suggested might be the only option

Comment: meant: a custom TransformationList can be as modifiable as needed - but then it's a custom implementation again ... probably should let my subconsiousness do some work before going any further, fog needs to settle ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra - JavaFX doesn't seem to have a 'vetoable change listener' capability. Is this by design? Or a side effect resulting from the departure of the responsible developer? Do you see a place for this, assuming it was possible? This would be like a conventional 'constrained property' where the new value is tested before it gets set to the property, i.e. it's ..NOT.. a (i) set value, (ii) check if valid, then (iii) rollback if the change is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. The required feature was implemented one year later in `TestFX`.

[Add support for propagating uncaught exceptions that occur on the JavaFX Application Thread. Issue #155](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/issues/155#issuecomment-336698350)

Comment: thanks for the info - personally, I'm not using TestFX, but might be good to know for others :)