# JavaFX: Not being able to catch an Exception in spinner's increment method

Tags: java, exception, javafx, spinner

I am not being able to catch an `Exception` (specifically `IllegalArgumentException`, although I don't think the problem is related to that) in my JavaFX application.

For context, this appeared when trying to dynamically set the max value for a spinner. Or more correctly (since the max value cannot be altered after creation), not incrementing if an `IllegalArgumentException` appeared. For this, I set my own `DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory`, which extends the `IntegerSpinnerValueFactory` provided by JavaFX.

Since the spinner is for use in a `TableView`, I also implemented a `IntegerSpinnerTableCellFactory` to make a column of spinners. I've included the code just to be able to provide a MWE, but you can (in principle) ignore this bit since the problem shouldn't be there.

`Furnishing` is my object from which to populate the table. The setter for `owned` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if we set more than a certain amount.

The `fxml` and the `FurnishingsTabController` are just your run of the mill stuff to make the window, load the table, etc... The `Main` class is just to make a list of dummy values and launch the program.

## Summary

This was my thought process to dynamically bound a spinner: have the setter throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in certain conditions and have the `increment` and `decrement` methods of the spinner factory `DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory` catch that exception. When caught, the methods wouldn't increment/decrement the value.

To reproduce the problem, run `Main` and increase one of the spinners to more than 10. The exception should be thrown in the console, but not caught by the `try`...`catch` in `DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory`.

PS: All code is provided below.

## CODE

### `DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory` (where the `Exception` is not being caught)

```java
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory;

public class DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory extends IntegerSpinnerValueFactory{

    public DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory(int min, int max) {
        super(min, max);
    }
    
    public DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory(int min, int max, int initialValue) {
        super(min, max, initialValue);
    }
    
    public DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory(int min, int max, int initialValue, int amountToStepBy) {
        super(min, max, initialValue, amountToStepBy);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void decrement(int steps) {
        int newValue = getValue() - steps;
        int min = getMin();
        
        if (newValue >= min)
            setValue(newValue);     
    }

    @Override
    public void increment(int steps) {
        int newValue = getValue() + steps;
        int max = getMax();
        
        if (newValue <= max) {
            try {
                setValue(newValue);
            }
            
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Hello"); //Exception not being caught since Hello is not being printed!
            }
            
            catch(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("World"); //Problem is not related with IllegalArgumentException since this isn't caught either...
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

### `Furnishing` (setter throws `IllegalArgumentException`)

```java
public class Furnishing {
    
    private String name;
    private int owned;
        
    public Furnishing(String name, int owned) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owned = owned;
    }
    
    public int getOwned() {
        return owned;
    }
    
    public void setOwned(int owned) {
        if (owned < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Owned amount must be >= 0.");
        
        if (owned > 10) //Just a small number to be easier to trigger the exception
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Limiting the amount of owned to 10");
        
        this.owned = owned; 
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;   
    }
}
```

### `Main`

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Furnishing> furnishings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        
        furnishings.add(new Furnishing("Curtains", 2));
        furnishings.add(new Furnishing("Cushions", 4));
        furnishings.add(new Furnishing("Sofas", 1));
        
        //Load the fxml
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FurnishingsTab.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        
        //Get the controller
        FurnishingsTabController furnishingsTabController = loader.getController();
        
        //Load tables
        furnishingsTabController.loadTable(furnishings);        
        
        //Set the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }

}
```

### `FurnishingsTableController`

```java
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class FurnishingsTabController {
    //Furnishings table
    @FXML private TableView<Furnishing> furnishingsTableView;
    
    //Furnishings table columns
    @FXML private TableColumn<Furnishing, String> furnishingsTabItemColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Furnishing, Integer> furnishingsTabOwnedColumn;
    
    //Spinner factories
    private IntegerSpinnerTableCellFactory<Furnishing> ownedColumnSpinnerFactory = new IntegerSpinnerTableCellFactory<>();
    
    public void initialize() {      
        //Item column       
        furnishingsTabItemColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        
        //Owned column
        furnishingsTabOwnedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("owned"));
        furnishingsTabOwnedColumn.setCellFactory(ownedColumnSpinnerFactory);
                
        ownedColumnSpinnerFactory.setUpdater((furnishing, newValue) -> {
            furnishing.setOwned(newValue);
        });
        
        return;
    }
    
    public void loadTable(ObservableList<Furnishing> furnishings) {
        furnishingsTableView.setItems(furnishings);
    }
}
```

### `IntegerSpinnerTableCellFactory` (a factory to provide spinners in `TableCells`; here for MWE but you can probably ignore this)

```java
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class IntegerSpinnerTableCellFactory<S> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, Integer>, TableCell<S, Integer>> {
        
    private BiConsumer<S, Integer> updater = null;
    
    public void setUpdater(BiConsumer<S, Integer> updater) {
        this.updater = updater;
    }
    
    @Override
    public TableCell<S, Integer> call(TableColumn<S, Integer> param) {
        return new TableCell<S, Integer>() {
            
            SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> factory = new DynamicIntegerSpinnerValueFactory(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);
            //Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(0, maxValue, 0);
            Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(factory);
            
            {
                //Set the duration between changes (when pressing and holding the arrow) to 30 ms
                spinner.repeatDelayProperty().set(new Duration(30));
                
                //Set the style for horizontal split arrows
                spinner.getStyleClass().add(Spinner.STYLE_CLASS_SPLIT_ARROWS_HORIZONTAL);
                
                spinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {                  
                    if (updater != null)
                        updater.accept(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()), newValue);
                });
                
            }
            
            protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                
                else {
                    spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(getItem());
                    setGraphic(spinner);
                }
            }           
        };
    }
}
```

### `FXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="FurnishingsTabController">
   <children>
      <TextField />
      <TableView fx:id="furnishingsTableView" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="furnishingsTabItemColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Item" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="furnishingsTabOwnedColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Owned" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="furnishingsTabDeployedColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Deployed" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="furnishingsTabRemainingColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Remaining" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="furnishingsTabUsedColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Used" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="furnishingsTabAvailableColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Available" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

Comment: TL DR. Please provide [mre]. Mind the M

Comment: one problem after another: make your factory work as expected (btw: don't quite understand what you are trying to do there - why not simply calling setMax when hitting the bounds if you want to dynamically adjust the min/max?), if that's done move on to more complex contexts. When stuck anywhere, come back with a [mcve] (NOT your complete code!) as @c0der already suggested :) That said: exceptions in listener chains are internally handed over to the uncaughtExceptionHandler so wont show up in client code, see f.i. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40242090/203657.

Comment: `public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception` I would suggest not throwing your exceptions at this level. Catch those and print the exception. I don't know the rules related to catching and throwing exceptions, but what I do is throw in any library I create. I throw if needed when `implementing` or `extending` a class. Almost everything else, I catch and handle the exceptions or print a message so that I can know where the problem exists. You seem to be throwing and/or catching at will.

Comment: @kleopatra Well, this is not the full code, and I did try my best to make it minimal...

Comment: in addition to my comment to your answer: changing the data from a cell under-the-feet of the editing mechanism is veeery thin ice (not without precedent, though - CheckBox cells do it as well ;) The exceptions from the data object smell: why don't you silently limit them to their min/max, just as a integerValueFactory?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it never will hit the getter, because the table cell value factory uses reflection to get or set the value.

`furnishingsTabOwnedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("owned"));` this factory relies upon reflection to access the values.

So, you have to throw the exception (or restrict the values) either in the increment/decrement methods of spinner factory or in the set value.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to circumvent the problem. For some reason (which was what I was trying to ask) I cannot catch exceptions in the `increment()` from the spinner factory.

What I did was using a custom `QuadriConsumer` updater (instead of a `BiConsumer` one), and pass the `spinner` and the `oldValue` to it. Then I can catch the `Exception` in the controller and prevent the spinner from changing, which was my original goal.

Comment: this smells like fixing a xy-problem - actually, I don't quite understand _what_ your goal is: what is "Dynamic" in your custom factory? The value of an integerFactory is bounded by min/max, without throwing when trying to set values out off bounds (neither by directly setting it nor during incr/decr). So you are expecting the exception (which seems to be thrown by your custom data class, which in itself might or might not a bad design desicion - exceptions are for thingies going wrong ;) to somehow bubble up to the incr/decr of the valueFactory?

Comment: @kleopatra Maybe the I shouldn't have used dynamic here. What I meant was the following: when a certain value is out of bounds (to be determined by the model), the spinner shouldn't increment to that value. I did consider if throwing an `Exception` would be the best way to handle this. From what I've read, throwing `IllegalArgumentException` when an argument is out of bounds (e.g. in a setter) seems to be a good practice. What I wanted from the spinner was to catch such exceptions and stopped the shown value from changing. Under the hood, the spinner's min and max are the same though.

Comment: then let the valuefactory respect the model's min/max .. that will take care of the value not being off range. It's wrong to have a model with an unspecified precondition (read: which throws an exception for certain arbitrary values). Why doesn't your model has min/max api or some means to check whether the value is valid?